# Duplicate questions accepted answers section

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, duplicate-answers

As there are different ways to complete a task, there can be several good and helpful approaches answered on duplicate questions.

I suggest a feature to add a section on `Duplicate Question` like `Similar Question Accepted answers`, so it would provide multiple tested and correct approaches on a single page. Usually duplicate question has links of other questions but have to visit individually each question.

Here I tried to create a rough mock-up for feature:

As a question get closed as Duplicated:

> [image: Duplicate Question]

Now on Answer List show a section:

> [image: Section]

On clicking this section. All the accepted answers(if exist)of the question mentioned as Possible Duplicate shown:

> [image: Duplicate Accepted Answers]

It would be really helpful section.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Not really following this one - can you do a screen mockup or something?

Comment: Added some rough mock-up

Comment: Brilliant idea! +1! I hate clicking at the duplicate link when the first post doesn't have (satisfactory) answers.

Comment: @11684 have to face the same & hate it

Answer (score 2):

Now that the approach of duplicate questions have changed, it's an excellent suggestion!

There are a few edges to iron out (What to do with older duplicates which don't necessarily have answers? Do you show the *accepted* answer or the *top voted* one?)

But a very good suggestion, perhaps even make it somewhere more visible (like a differently colored answer among the other answers).